# Escape newline character while encoding in base64

Tags: bash

I have a situation where in my BASH script, I need to encode an environment variable to base64 and write it to a json file, which is then picked up by docker.

I have the below code for this:

```
USER64=$(echo $USER | base64)
echo '{"auths": {"auth": "'"$USER64"'}}' > ~/.docker/config.json
```

This works, but the problem is the encoded value of `$USER` contains a `\n` so the echo writes it into the config file as 2 lines. How can I escape all the `\n` while encoding the `$USER` and write it to the config file?

Comment: Use `base64 --wrap=0` to disable line wrapping.

Comment: Use `jq` to create and parse JSON in shell scripts, rather than doing it with string substitution.

Comment: @Barmar the base64 encoded value has the `\n`, so I believe the value of `$USER64` needs to be updated by escaping it. So `--wrap=0` won't help, right?

Comment: The newline is coming from the automatic wrapping. --wrap=0 tells it not to wrap every 76 characters.

Comment: `USER64=$(echo $USER | base64 --wrap=0)`

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help!

Comment: Why is your username so long that base64 results in 2 lines?

Comment: When I try that, `$USER64` is `YmFybWFyCg==` with no newlines in it.

Comment: Ah I think there is a misunderstanding, the base64 encoded value of the USER64 contains a \n character. So when I write this whole value to the config json, its interpreted as a new line.

Comment: So basically I need to do something like: `USER64.replace("\n", "\\\n")` if that is more clear.

Comment: Why does the base64 encoded value contain a `\n` character? Where is that coming from?

Comment: As I said, when I ran your code, I don't get a newline character anywhere.

Comment: I only get a newline in the base64 encoded value if `$USER` is at least 56 characters long.

Comment: But if I add `--wrap=0` I don't get a newline.

Comment: @barmar, the $USER is an api key which can be 56 or more in length. Thanks.

Comment: `$USER` is a standard environment variable, it contains the username of the logged in user. You shouldn't reuse it in your scripts. This is why you shouldn't use all-uppercase variable names, they're reserved for environment variables of standard utilities.

Comment: Ah, my bad! The actual variable name is quite different and long, I just used `$USER` here for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the substitution operator in shell parameter expansion.

```
echo '{"auths": {"auth": "'"${USER64/$'\n'/\\\n}"'}}' > ~/.docker/config.json
```

But you can also use an option to `base64` to prevent it from putting newlines into the encoding in the first place.

```
USER64=$(echo $USER | base64 --wrap=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

As added incentive to use `jq`, it can do the base64 encoding for you:

```
jq -n --arg u "$USER" '{auths: {auth: ($u | @base64)}}' > ~/.docker/config.json
```

(And as far as I can tell, `@base64` is working on the original value, not the JSON-encode value, of `$USER`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here I propose a simpler solution than the one given by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar).

You have to keep in mind that the echo command will add a new line character by default. So the encoded value will have a new character when you decode it.

My solution would be to encode it using the `-n` argument for echo command and the `--wrap=0` for base64:

```bash
USER64=$(echo -n $USER | base64 --wrap=0)
echo -n '{"auths": {"auth": "'"$USER64"'}}' > ~/.docker/config.json
```

This way you won't have any new line character.